# Error -Undefined variable: 'ModelSelect2Widget'

Tags: python, django, django-widget, django-select2

I am new to this field. I am working on Dependent Dropdowns for which i took reference from [here](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra.html). On replicating the same with the following code:

**Forms.py**

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model=City
       country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
          queryset=Country.objects.all(),
          label=u"Country",
          widget= ModelSelect2Widget(
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
            dependent_fields={'city': 'cities'},
           )
       )

   city = forms.ModelChoiceField(
       queryset=City.objects.all(),
       label=u"City",
       widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
           search_fields=['name__icontains'],
           dependent_fields={'country': 'country'},
           max_results=500,
       )
   )
```

Getting error

> Undefined variable: 'ModelSelect2Widget'

I also installed:

```
INSTALLED_APPS=[
                'django_select2',
                'django_q',
  ]
```

Comment: Have you imported `ModelSelect2Widget`?

Comment: hey @WBM I tried- from django_select2 import ModelSelect2Widget  but At the time of running server its giving error cannot import name 'ModelSelect2Widget' I hope my method is correct

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your import. In Select2, the ModelSelect2Widget class is in the forms module.
So your import should be as follows:

```
from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2Widget


class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model=City
       country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
          queryset=Country.objects.all(),
          label=u"Country",
          widget= ModelSelect2Widget(
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
            dependent_fields={'city': 'cities'},
           )
       )

   city = forms.ModelChoiceField(
       queryset=City.objects.all(),
       label=u"City",
       widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
           search_fields=['name__icontains'],
           dependent_fields={'country': 'country'},
           max_results=500,
       )
   )
```